# HTML5 number input - display as percentage instead of decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form including number inputs which are supposed to represent percentages, which are set up approximately like below:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" />
```

Currently, the values show up as decimals, for example, 0.25. I think it'd be a lot more user-friendly if the number displayed in the text field showed up as a percentage instead. I've already disabled keyboard input on the field using the below jQuery code, so I'm not worried about users inputting rogue values:

```
$('input[type="number"]').keypress(function (field) {
    field.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there an easy way to change the number fields to display a percentage?

Thank you!

Comment: You can set min to 0, max to 100, step to 1 and divide the value in JS by 100 on the output.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Do you want to submit that as an answer so I can pick it?

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways which I hope will work.

If you want percentages in input and need to convert it to decimals in js then:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" id="myPercent"/>
```

in js:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
    var valInDecimals = document.getElementById('myPercent').value / 100;
}
```

If scenario is reverse then:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" id="myPercent"/>
```

in js:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
    var valInDecimals = document.getElementById('myPercent').value * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

While not a HTML5 `input type='number'`, the solution below uses `input type='text'` to the same effect. The rationale of not using `type='number'` being humans require a nicely formatted string like "23.75%" while robots prefer to read integers and floating points should be avoided. The snippet below does just that to 2 decimal places.

I haven't tested it on a mobile, but I think the number pad should appear as with `input type='number'`.

Codepen.io: [Commented code can be found here](https://codepen.io/tomasMetcalfe/pen/poojJLE?editors=1111)

```js
document.querySelector('.percent').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let int = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.value.length - 1);

  if (int.includes('%')) {
    e.target.value = '%';
  } else if(int == '100'){
    e.target.value = int + '%';
    e.target.setSelectionRange(3, 3);
  } else if (int.length >= 3 && int.length <= 4 && !int.includes('.')) {
    e.target.value = int.slice(0, 2) + '.' + int.slice(2, 3) + '%';
    e.target.setSelectionRange(4, 4);
  } else if (int.length >= 5 & int.length <= 6) {
    let whole = int.slice(0, 2);
    let fraction = int.slice(3, 5);
    e.target.value = whole + '.' + fraction + '%';
  } else {
    e.target.value = int + '%';
    e.target.setSelectionRange(e.target.value.length - 1, e.target.value.length - 1);
  }
  console.log('For robots: ' + getInt(e.target.value));
});

function getInt(val) {
  let v = parseFloat(val);
  if (v % 1 === 0) {
    return v;
  } else {
    let n = v.toString().split('.').join('');
    return parseInt(n);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="percent" type="text" value="23.75%" maxlength="6">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a function, the outputted number (for example 0.25) * 100 + "%", on this way you always have it in percents.

```
function topercentage() {
    var outputnumber = outputnumber * 100 + "%";
}
```

In this example outputnumber is the number for example 0.25. I hope this works.