# how to set % symbol for input type number field

Tags: html, angularjs

How to set % symbol default for the input type "number" field . I am using input type number field when I try to enter anything I want to show the input field with % symbol

Comment: Use normal text type input and use js to prevent other char except %

Comment: Does the final value need to become a string like this: "10%"? If yes, you can modify the value at the end before saving/using it and just write a "%" next to the input field to make the user understand he has to input a number that is a percentage. p.s. Yeah you can also use javascript to limit the characters the user can input, like Rakesh Soni said.

Comment: Impossible to use a char in a `number` input. Have to use type `text` instead

Comment: This link will help for you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041647/html5-number-input-display-as-percentage-instead-of-decimal

Comment: This link will help you https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/sxh22hfz/

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for this, check below snippet

```css
.input-group {
    display: table;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
.input-group .form-control {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
.input-group .input-group-addon {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #2f353e;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
 <input name="number" type="number" id="number" class="form-control" />
 <label class="input-group-addon" for="number">%</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: I want to display the % symbol with in input field after the number

Comment: If you need to display `%` character inside input field then,  Use javascript to limit the characters the user can input, like Rakesh Soni/nonzaprej  said.