# How to add percentage symbol at end of input value in input field with yup validation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js13, yup

[image]

How to add a **percentage symbol** at the end of the input value in the input filed with **yup validation**? Here I am using the JavaScript in-built method to covert percentage

```
<FormField
  control={form.control}
  name="additionalTax"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <FormItem>
      <FormControl className="relative">
        <Input
          {...field}
          value={percentageFormat.format(
            Number(field?.value?.replace("%", "")) / 100
          )}
          className=" py-5 text-start text-lg"
          disabled={!form.getValues("isIndirectTax")}
          onChange={(e) => {
            const val = e.target.value;
            console.log(val);
            field.onChange(val);
          }}
          onFocus={(e) => {
            const input = e.target;
            const value = input.value;
            const percentIndex = value.indexOf("%");

            if (percentIndex !== -1) {
              console.log(percentIndex);
              // Move the cursor before the '%' symbol
              input.setSelectionRange(value.length - 1, value.length - 1);
            }
          }}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <FormMessage className="text-sx text-brand inline-flex" />
    </FormItem>
  )}
/>;
```

I want to dynamically add the percentage symbol at the end of the input value while changing

Comment: Is this just for a visual or part of the actual value of a text input?

Comment: You would have to check for the percentage sign onChange and do calculations only on the numbers, a quick search showed me something similar, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58324366/2363810

Comment: Only for visual